# Variable with a dictionary is interpreted as string when passed as map parameter

Tags: dictionary, filter, ansible

I have a YAML structure describing a set of usergroups, one of the elements being a list of usernames. I'm trying to design simple filters or tasks that replace the sub-element of this list of members in each group by a new one.

Executing the following playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: no

  vars:
    my_groups:
      group1:
        members: [alice, bob, john]
        comment: first group
        sudoers: yes
      group2:
        members: [alice, john]
        comment: second group
        sudoers: no
    new_users_list: [alice, bob]

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      new_members: "{{ { 'members': new_users_list } }}"
  - debug:
      var: new_members
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ my_groups | map('combine', new_members ) }}"
```

gives the following result for the last task:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'str' and a 'dict': \n"all"\n{"members": ["alice", "bob"]}"}

I was expecting to see the replacement of the list `members` by the list given as parameter of combined filter. But now I understand I am wrong: not only the structure I try to combine lacks the level of the groupname but also, most of all, it seems that the `map` filter expects a list (or applies a `| list` filter).

How can I pass a a dict as an argument of the `combine` filter that `map` filter applies to each element of a dict?

Note that the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: new_members
```

Correctly interprets the variable as a dictionary:

```json
{
    "new_members": {
        "members": [
            "alice",
            "bob"
        ]
    }
}
```

My expected output is to intersect the existing member list with the new members one:

```yaml
my_groups:
  group1:
    comment: first group
    members:
      - alice
      - bob
    sudoers: true
  group2:
    comment: second group
    members:
      - alice
    sudoers: false
```

Comment: (a) you cannot use jinja2 mustaches in a `vars` file, what's happening is that ansible is recursively evaluating those mustaches when it uses them (b) you've said what it isn't doing but not what you are expecting to happen. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Comment: Thanks for your time and your comment @mdaniel, and sorry I presumed I knew the rules enough. (a) AFAIK, I think the moustaches in the `new_members` variable definition are ok. I tried them as playbook declared vars, and now with `set_fact`: they work ok and give what I expect. (b) You're right, I was in my bubble. I edited my post, breifly described my goal and what I expect, and gave a complete playbook that should run with a simple copy/paste. Hope it's now ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial trial, as well as your own proposed solution are complex because you are trying to act on the dictionary right away — while you will get an expected result easier if you `map` an a list.

Now, because your goal is to intersect the existing members with a new set of members, this won't be really practical in a map, because you have to get the current group members to intersect it with the new members, and, as far as I know, you cannot get something similar to an item of a loop in a `map`.

Now, to simplify your solution, you have to look at the [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries) and [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) filters than can help you transform a list in an dictionary and vice versa.

With those, you could have those two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    new_groups: >-
      {{
        new_groups | d([])
        + [item | combine(_replacement_group, recursive=True)]
      }}
  loop: "{{ my_groups | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
  vars:
    _replacement_group:
      value:
        members: "{{ item.value.members | intersect(new_users_list) }}"

- debug:
    var: new_groups | items2dict
```

Which would be fitting your requirements:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  new_groups | items2dict:
    group1:
      comment: first group
      members:
      - alice
      - bob
      sudoers: true
    group2:
      comment: second group
      members:
      - alice
      sudoers: false
```

Answer (score 0):

The example I posted was in fact an intermediate test that failed, my final goal was not to replace the list of members of the group, but to intersect it with a fixed list (the structure of groups is defined for the whole IaC, the list of users are those of a specific host).

I could solve the problem with the following loop that recursively defines the modified structure of groups:

```
- name: Loop to build the groups of the host
  set_fact:
    new_groups: >
            {{ new_groups | default({}) 
            | combine ( { current_groupname: current_group | combine ( new_group_members ) } ) }}
  loop: '{{ my_groups | list }}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: current_groupname
  vars:
    current_group: '{{ my_groups | json_query ( current_groupname ) }}'
    new_group_members: '{{ { "members": current_group.members | intersect( new_users_list ) } }}'
```

Running with the data in the initial post, it provides:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_groups": {
        "group1": {
            "comment": "first group",
            "members": [
                "alice",
                "bob"
            ],
            "sudoers": true
        },
        "group2": {
            "comment": "second group",
            "members": [
                "alice"
            ],
            "sudoers": false
        }
    }
}
```

So problem solved. But, as I came here, a stronger refactor is always beautiful: is there a simpler way to code and run this task, for instance with filters like `map` or `json_query`?